# Access parent alias in subquery within a with clause using connect by in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, nested, connect, ora-00904

I'm trying to recursively get some data using connect by, which for each row I need to know if in a different tree contains a specific item.

So I have this [stripped down] query:

```
select m.id, m.name,
   (select (
    with recursiveMetaClass as (
            select mb.name
            from meta mb
            start with mb.id = m.id
            connect by prior mb.metaclass = mb.id and mb.metaclass <> mb.id
    ) select name from recursiveMetaClass where name in ('config_group', 'config_item')
   ) from dual) as basetype
from meta m
inner join meta_rel mr on mr.rel2 = m.id
start with m.name = 'store_sys'
connect by prior m.id = mr.rel1
order siblings by item_order;
```

This errors though with ORA-00904 "M"."ID": invalid identifier on m.id in start with in my nested query.  If I replace with query with:

```
select m.id, m.name,
   (select (
    with recursiveMetaClass as (
            select mb.name
            from meta mb
            start with mb.id = 1004
            connect by prior mb.metaclass = mb.id and mb.metaclass <> mb.id
    ) select name from recursiveMetaClass where name in ('config_group', 'config_item')
   ) from dual) as basetype
from meta m
inner join meta_rel mr on mr.rel2 = m.id
start with m.name = 'store_sys'
connect by prior m.id = mr.rel1
order siblings by item_order;
```

It works (just gives wrong results).

How can I either get m.id into that start with, or refactor this to work?  I also tried using some nested selects and doing a where on rownumber = 1 order by level desc, however I get the exact same error when trying to reference m.id.

Thank you!

Comment: Oracle9i Release 9.2.0.7.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: I'm not really an expert at this, but what happens if you try to use the non-aliased version? `start with mb.id = meta.id`

Comment: The non stripped down version has multiple joins to meta, so that will not work.

Comment: It seems newer versions resolve this, but I'm not sure how to make it work by pulling the variable through the queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you simplify this query to the following?

```
select m.id, m.name, 
(      select mb.name  
       from meta mb 
       where name in ('config_group', 'config_item') 
       start with mb.id = m.id 
       connect by prior mb.metaclass = mb.id and mb.metaclass <> mb.id 
) as basetype
from meta m  
inner join meta_rel mr on mr.rel2 = m.id 
start with m.name = 'store_sys' 
connect by prior m.id = mr.rel1 
order siblings by item_order;
```

Comment: Wow, I figured the connect by would stop when name wasn't in one of those two as opposed to just ignore that row but continue joining.  Thank you!